How should I handle Entity Framework Core omitting explicit values (IsActive = 0) when seeding my database?
I am using ASP.NET Core, SQLite to create a bank style application. When I update and seed my database EF Core is not recognizing or ignoring IsActive = 0 which is causing all my BankAccount to be created with the default value of 1. Is there an issue in how I have created my table, how I am seeding my database, or something else?
Here is the seeding statement:
modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>().HasData(
            new BankAccount {
                PkAccountId = 1,
                FkAccountTypeId = 1,
                Balance = 1500.00M,
                IsActive = 1,
                DateOpened = DateTime.Parse("2024/03/09")
            },
            new BankAccount {
                PkAccountId = 2,
                FkAccountTypeId = 2,
                Balance = 3000.00M,
                IsActive = 0,
                DateOpened = DateTime.Parse("2020/06/01")
            },
            new BankAccount {
                PkAccountId = 3,
                FkAccountTypeId = 3,
                Balance = 8000.00M,
                IsActive = 1,
                DateOpened = DateTime.Parse("2021/01/01")
            },
            new BankAccount {
                PkAccountId = 4,
                FkAccountTypeId = 4,
                Balance = 12000.00M,
                IsActive = 1,
                DateOpened = DateTime.Parse("2024/07/06")
            },
            new BankAccount {
                PkAccountId = 5,
                FkAccountTypeId = 5,
                Balance = 4500.00M,
                IsActive = 1,
                DateOpened = DateTime.Parse("2020/03/08")
            });

And a screenshot of the execution of the above commands:
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Bank Account" ("PkAccountId", "Balance", "DateOpened", "FkAccountTypeId", "IsActive")
      VALUES (1, '1500.0', '2024-03-09 00:00:00', 1, 1);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Bank Account" ("PkAccountId", "Balance", "DateOpened", "FkAccountTypeId")
      VALUES (2, '3000.0', '2020-06-01 00:00:00', 2);
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "Bank Account" ("PkAccountId", "Balance", "DateOpened", "FkAccountTypeId", "IsActive")
      VALUES (3, '8000.0', '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 3, 1);
      INSERT INTO "Bank Account" ("PkAccountId", "Balance", "DateOpened", "FkAccountTypeId", "IsActive")
      VALUES (4, '12000.0', '2024-07-06 00:00:00', 4, 1);
      INSERT INTO "Bank Account" ("PkAccountId", "Balance", "DateOpened", "FkAccountTypeId", "IsActive")
      VALUES (5, '4500.0', '2020-03-08 00:00:00', 5, 1);

Here is my table creation:
modelBuilder.Entity<BankAccount>(entity =>
        {
            // Table Name
            entity.ToTable("Bank Account");

            // Primary Key
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PkAccountId);
            entity.Property(e => e.PkAccountId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            // Properties
            entity.Property(e => e.DateOpened)
                  .HasColumnType("TEXT")
                  .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now)
                  .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.Balance)
                  .HasColumnType("REAL")
                  .IsRequired();

            entity.Property(e => e.IsActive)
                  .HasColumnType("INTEGER")
                  .HasDefaultValue(1)
                  .IsRequired();

            // Foreign Key Relationship
            entity.HasOne(e => e.BankAccountType)
                  .WithMany(e => e.BankAccounts)
                  .HasForeignKey(e => e.FkAccountTypeId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        });

I initially thought maybe there was an issue with how SQLite was creating the tables so I changed the column types to match the available column types in SQLite from varchar(50), decimal(9, 2), etc.
I also thought maybe there was a problem with my range constraint so I removed that and also added a default constructor to the Models. None of these changes impacted the creation of the tables or the seeding from what I could figure out.

You've forgotten to include the value of IsActive in your insert statement for account 2, so it takes the default value, which is 1. Either include it in the insert statement or change the default to 0.

I have IsActive=0 declared in the insert statement for account 2 which is where I’m getting confused in how to address this issue. The code is ignoring my explicit IsActive definition and not reading it because I believe it’s treating 0 as a falsy value instead of an integer with value 0.

Which EF version is this?

@GertArnold I am using Visual Studio for Mac so I had to set up my project with .NET 7.0. EF Core version 7.0.20

This can only be solved by using EFC8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#sentinel-values-and-database-defaults

Great, thank you! I was worried that might be the case. I have fixed the problem on my end by using .ValueGeneratedNever() but I'm not sure if this is a great way to handle this issue.

I think the problem is in .HasDefaultValue(1).
Maybe EF recognizes the value 0 as uninitialized for the int type. Why not make this property a bool type?

Unfortunately SQLite does not have a Boolean data type. It instead treats true and false as 1 and 0 respectively. With that being said, I’ll try setting IsActive = false and see if EF keeps the 0 value after the conversion
